# how to set ckediter4 plugin html video z-index

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

the plugin url:https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/video,
in this plugin,I added a button,onlick function like this:

```
onClick: function() {
        $('.bs-example-modal-lg').modal('show');
      }
```

I setted the dialog(css is bs-example-modal-lg)'s z-index is 999999,but not work.
the dialog(css is bs-example-modal-lg) still showed behind the video dialog;

please tell me how to set video dialog's z-index ,let it show behind the dialog(css is bs-example-modal-lg)

Comment: I define the style error..